# Sorting Lists of lists of arbitrary length

Tags: sorting, list-manipulation

I'm trying to sort a list of lists.  The sublists are defined in length, but the length of the list containing it varies.

A simplified set might be:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {7, 1, 4}, {3, 5, 6}, {10, 7, 1}}
```

but it could be:

```
a={{1, 2, 3}, {7, 1, 4}, {3, 5, 6}, {10, 7, 1}, {12, 4, 8}}
```

Sorting on the last element is built-in using

```
SortBy[a,Last];
```

How do I sort on an arbitrary element?  In the example, the second.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To sort by a specific element use a pure function with the number in question. For your case (the second element) just do:

```
SortBy[a, #[[2]] &]
```

> ```
>  {{7, 1, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {12, 4, 8}, {3, 5, 6}, {10, 7, 1}}
> ```

You can also use `Sort` like this:

```
Sort[a, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &]
```

Comment: worked beautifully, thanks!

Comment: @RickR You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 8):

There is also ... `Ordering`

```
ClearAll[sortBy];
sortBy[list_, column_, ord_: Less] := list[[Ordering[list[[All, column]], All, ord]]]
```

Examples:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {7, 1, 4}, {3, 5, 6}, {10, 7, 1}, {12, 4, 8}};  
sortBy[a, 2]
(* {{7,1,4},{1,2,3},{12,4,8},{3,5,6},{10,7,1}} *)

sortBy[a, 2, Greater]
(* {{10,7,1},{3,5,6},{12,4,8},{1,2,3},{7,1,4}} *)

Row[MatrixForm /@ (MapAt[Style[#, Red, Bold, 18] &, 
                         sortBy[a, #], {{All, #}}] & /@ {1, 2, 3})]
```

[image]

```
Row[MatrixForm /@ (MapAt[Style[#, Red, Bold, 18] &, 
                         sortBy[a, #, Greater], {{All, #}}] & /@ {1, 2, 3})]
```

[image]

Comment: oh, that's pretty cool.  thanks for sharing/enlightening!

Comment: @RickR, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Answer (score 2):

Operator form of `SortBy`

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {7, 1, 4}, {3, 5, 6}, {10, 7, 1}, {12, 4, 8}};

a // SortBy[Last]
```

> {{10, 7, 1}, {1, 2, 3}, {7, 1, 4}, {3, 5, 6}, {12, 4, 8}}

```
 SortBy[#[[2]] &] @ a
```

> {7, 1, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {12, 4, 8}, {3, 5, 6}, {10, 7, 1}}